# What is the time complexity of this code? Is it O(logn) or O(loglogn)?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, time-complexity, big-o

```
int n = 8; // In the video n = 8  
int p = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2) { // In the video i = 1
    p++;
}
for (int j = 1; j < p; j *= 2) { // In the video j = 1
    //code;
}
```

> This is code from Abdul Bari Youtube channel ( [link of the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SgLBjXqwd4)), they said time complexity of this is O(loglogn) but I think it is O(log), what is the correct answer?

Comment: the code does not terminate. you multiply i by two, but it always stays 0

Comment: @jjj Presumably the initial value in both loops is 1.

Comment: Also the complexity heavily depends on `//code;` part. What exactly prevents another loop there?

Comment: For any practical purposes `log n < 32` and `log log n < 5` for `int n` so you may treat those almost as some small constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are correct**, the time complexity of the complete code is O(log(n)).

But, **Abdul Bari Sir is also correct**, Because:-

In the video, Abdul Sir is trying to find the time complexity of the second `for loop` and not the time complexity of the whole code. Take a look at the video again and listen properly what he is saying at this time https://youtu.be/9SgLBjXqwd4?t=568

Once again, what he has derived is the time complexity of the second loop and not the time complexity of the complete code. Please listen to what he says at 9 mins and 28 secs in the video.

If your confusion is clear, please mark this as correct.

Answer (score 4):

Fix the initial value. `0` multiplied by `2` will never end the loop.

The last loop is `O(log log N)` because `p == log(n)`. However, the first loop is `O(log N)`, hence in total it is also `O(log N)`.

On the other hand, once you put some code in place of `//code` then the first loop can be negligible compared to the second and we have:

```
O ( log N   +  X * log log N)
     ^ first loop
               ^ second loop
```

and when `X` is just big enough, one can consider it as `O( log log N)` in total. However strictly speaking that is wrong, because complexity is about asymptotic behavior and no matter how big `X`, for `N` going to infinity, `log N` will always be bigger than `X * log log N` at some point.

PS: I assumed that `//code` does not depend on `N`, ie it has constant complexity. The above consideration changes if this is not the case.

PPS: In general complexity is important when designing algorithms. When using an algorithm it is rather irrelevant. In that case you rather care about actual runtime for your specific value of `N`. Complexity can be misleading and even lead to wrong expectations for a specific use case with given `N`.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity of

```
int n;
int p = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2) { // start at 1, not at 0
    p++;
}
```

is O(log(n)), because you do p++ log2(n) times. The logarithms base does not matter in big O notation, because it just scales by a constant.

```
for (int j = 1; j < p; j *= 2) {
    //code;
}
```

has O(log(log(n)), because you only loop up to p=log(n) by multiplying, so you have O(log(p)), so O(log(log(n)).

However, both together still are O(log(n)), because O(log(n)+log(log(n)))=O(log(n)

Comment: the `log log N` is coming from the second loop, that you decided to ignore ;)

Comment: The 2nd loop does not change the time complexity, because it's faster, but I added this now.